# Reactjs Context don't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

here's the code working:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bug-context-sptwvg?file=/src/templates/CardsTemplate.tsx

all my context work well, i can search for a card and the api give me the results, but i dont uderstand why the CardsTemplate dont update the list, when i try a console.log(cardsList) or in loading, it don't update, anyone now a solution?

```
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { useCardsContext } from "hooks";
import { CardShow } from "components/Items";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  cards: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",

    justifyContent: "center",
    gap: 10,
    padding: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});

function CardsTemplate() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { cardsList, loading } = useCardsContext();

  return (
    <Grid className={classes.cards}>
      {loading ? (
        <p>carregando...</p>
      ) : cardsList?.data?.length > 0 ? (
        cardsList.data.map((card, index) => (
          <Grid>
            <CardShow key={index} card={card} />
          </Grid>
        ))
      ) : (
        <p>procure um card</p>
      )}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default CardsTemplate;
```

Comment: From what I can see, you are using your `CardProvider` as a wrapper in multiple places, I would suggest only wrapping your top `App` component with the Provider and see if that works since you won't be creating multiple instances of that same Context Provider.

Comment: thanks, i do as you say and worked

Comment: Great, should I move my comment to an answer so you can close this thread?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using your `CardProvider` as a wrapper in multiple places/components, this is why your `CardsTemplate` is not accessing the correct data. To fix this you just need to wrap only your `App` top component (which is your app's entry point) with the Provider. This way your data will be accessible from anywhere in your app and you will have a single source of truth for this data, therefore, avoiding inconsistencies.